# Make content infinite scroll left to right

Tags: html, css, animation

Looking to make a continuous logo slider but this code I created keeps stopping and it isn't continuous. Any ideas why?

```
<div class="slider-container">
<div class="slider-content"> CONTENT 1 </div>
<div class="slider-content"> CONTENT 2 </div>
<div class="slider-content"> CONTENT 3 </div>
</div>

      .slide-container{
      overflow: hidden;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    
    .slide-content{
      overflow: hidden;
      display: inline-block;
      animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
    
    }
    
    @keyframes marquee {
      0% {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have attached a sample code for you.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="pink">CONTENT 1</div>
    <div class="blue">CONTENT 2</div>
    <div class="yellow">CONTENT 3</div>
    <div class="orange">CONTENT 4</div>
    <div class="purple">CONTENT 5</div>
    <div class="aqua">CONTENT 6</div>
</div>
<style>
    .container {
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        height: 500px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .container div {
        height: 400px;
        min-width: 200px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        animation: slide 15s linear infinite;
    }

    .pink {
        background-color: pink;
        padding: 250px;
    }

    .blue {
        background-color: blue;
        padding: 250px;
    }

    .yellow {
        background-color: yellow;
        padding: 250px;
    }

    .orange {
        background-color: orange;
        padding: 250px;
    }

    .purple {
        background-color: purple;
        padding: 250px;
    }

    .aqua {
        background-color: aqua;
        padding: 250px;
    }

    @keyframes slide {
        0% {
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }

        100% {
            transform: translate3d(-1500px, 0, 0);
            /* The image width */
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you but this isn't continuous,if you'll notice content number one jumps to the beginning and it isn't one continuous slide